# How to dynamically add a cell into an already defined table

Tags: html, html-table

I have an app which takes in donations for houses to a charity.

I am using a table which just displays the information and at the bottom of my page I have a total, which is just text that doesn't look pretty.

I'd rather have attached to my cells, preferably at the bottom right of my table.

I just can't find anything which helps me to do it apart from a W3Schools tutorial which adds a new cell with a button, which I don't want.

Here is my HTML (Side note: I'm using C# and Razor)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Donations", FormMethod.Get))
{ <div>
        <fieldset>
            <table style="border:none">
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="editor-label">Search Address:</label></td>
                    <td id="searchBar1">@Html.TextBox("SearchStringAddress")</td>
                    <td><label class="editor-label">Search House ID:</label></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td id="searchBar2">@Html.TextBox("SearchStringHouseNumber")</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
               </table>
            @if (TempData["Error"] != null)
            {
                <div style="color:red">@TempData["Error"]</div>
            }


        </fieldset>
    </div>

        <h2>List of Donations</h2>

        <p>
            <u> @Html.ActionLink("Add New Donation", "Create")</u>
        </p>
        <table class="tftable" id="tftable">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Church Name")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("House ID")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("House Address")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Type of Donation")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Date Recieved", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("TOTAL")
                </th>

            </tr>

            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    {
                        runningTotal += item.Amount;
                    }
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Church.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HouseId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.House.AddressLine1)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TypeOfDonation)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateRecieved)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
                        </td>


                    </tr>
                }
            }


        </table>


        <b>TOTAL: @runningTotal </b>
}
```

Is there any way of carrying this out?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Javascript for this or do you want to do it from server side/c#?

Comment: @andrralv javascript. Far easier that way I'd presume

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use Javascript you can add td elements to an existing table with just plain javascript:

```
var node = document.createElement("td");
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Some Text");
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.querySelector("table #row1").appendChild(node);
```

You could for instance use fetch or xmlhttprequest and query your server for data, then loop through the returned json/xml/txt to add new elements to your table.